# Looking for format for KeywordsField.save_form_data

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have a Mezzanine Project and am trying to update the keywords on a blog entry. I am having difficulty getting the format correct to call KeywordsField.save_form_data this invokes a js that will update the keywords on a blog post. See below:

From Messanine/generic/fields.py

```
class KeywordsField(BaseGenericRelation):
    """
Stores the keywords as a single string into the
``KEYWORDS_FIELD_NAME_string`` field for convenient access when
searching.
"""

    default_related_model = "generic.AssignedKeyword"
    fields = {"%s_string": CharField(editable=False, blank=True,
                                 max_length=500)}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Mark the field as editable so that it can be specified in
    admin class fieldsets and pass validation, and also so that
    it shows up in the admin form.
    """
        super(KeywordsField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.editable = True

        def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Provide the custom form widget for the admin, since there
    isn't a form field mapped to ``GenericRelation`` model fields.
    """
        from mezzanine.generic.forms import KeywordsWidget
        kwargs["widget"] = KeywordsWidget
        return super(KeywordsField, self).formfield(**kwargs)


        def save_form_data(self, instance, data):
    """
    The ``KeywordsWidget`` field will return data as a string of
    comma separated IDs for the ``Keyword`` model - convert these
    into actual ``AssignedKeyword`` instances. Also delete
    ``Keyword`` instances if their last related ``AssignedKeyword``
    instance is being removed.
    """
        from mezzanine.generic.models import Keyword
        related_manager = getattr(instance, self.name)
        # Get a list of Keyword IDs being removed.
        old_ids = [str(a.keyword_id) for a in related_manager.all()]
        new_ids = data.split(",")
        removed_ids = set(old_ids) - set(new_ids)
        # Remove current AssignedKeyword instances.
        related_manager.all().delete()
        # Convert the data into AssignedKeyword instances.
        if data:
            data = [related_manager.create(keyword_id=i) for i in new_ids]
        # Remove keywords that are no longer assigned to anything.
        Keyword.objects.delete_unused(removed_ids)
        super(KeywordsField, self).save_form_data(instance, data)
```

From my Views.py

```
class PubForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['keywords']


def UpdatePub(request, slug): 
    blog_post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = PubForm(request.POST)   
        if form.is_valid(): 
            publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            blog_post.status = CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED             
            publish_date=publish_date
            tags=form.cleaned_data['keywords']
            blog_post.save() 
            KeywordsField.save_form_data(user,blog_post,tags)       
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/write/') 
    else:
        form = PubForm(instance=blog_post)
    return render(request, 'blog_my_pub.html', {'form' : form})
```

It complains that the field 'user' has no attribute 'name'. I have tried many different values for this parameter and cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is KeywordsField? Why do you think you need to call that method?

Comment: And if you don't know what self means in a method, you should urgently do an introductory Python tutorial: that's absolutely basic knowledge for working with classes.

Comment: KeywordsField invokes an update to the keywords on the Mezzanine blog that will assign a string of keywords to a blog post, and then delete any keywords that no longer have any attached blogs. It also updates a meta field on the blog entry that summarizes the keywords into a list.  I am sorry if I have asked such a basic question on classes, but I have tried many different formats for this call. And like most programming, all I need to do is call the method correctly. Perhaps a hint?